# Why form_tag parameters are showed in my URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, parameters

I'm having the following problem.
I have a button that send the user to /user/:id, and its working well, but when a click I'm receiving in my URL:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1?utf8=✓&button=
```

And I don't want to show `?utf8=✓&button=`

The form_tag is sending

```
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "button"=>"", "id"=>"1"}
```

My button is:

```
<%= form_tag user_path(current_user), method: :get do %>
  <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-success" do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i> <%= current_user.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My routes:

```
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
```

Someone know how could I remove `?utf8=✓&button=` of my URL?

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT:

To solve this problem, I going to use link_to.

```
<%= link_to user_path(current_user), :class => "btn btn-success" do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i> <%= current_user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have any inputs in the form, there is really no need for a form. Simply change it to an anchor tag with `link_to` and you will be all set.

```
<%= link_to user_path(current_user), :class => "btn btn-success" do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i> <%= current_user.name %>
<% end %>
```

This will look exactly like your submit button. And the URL will simply be /user/:id.

Answer (score 2):

**GET**

The reason is because [you're using the `:get` method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Bottom line:

> - `Get` requests append params in URL
> - `Post` requests send params behind scenes

[image]

---

**Fix**

To fix this, you need to remove the `method: :get` from the form.

This will allow your form to send a `post` request, which will hide the params:

```
<%= form_tag user_path(current_user) do %>
```

However, a deeper question is *why* are you sending a `get` request with a form? It's okay to use this (as you're loading the correct resource for the form), but perhaps it would be better for you to use a [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) or similar?

If you give me a comment, I'll be in a much better position to help regarding a better solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

This is here to support Internet Explorer 5 and encourage it to use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for its forms.

The commit message seen [here](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/25215d7285db10e2c04d903f251b791342e4dd6a) details it as follows:

> Fix several known web encoding issues:
>
> - Specify accept-charset on all forms. All recent browsers,   as well as
>     IE5+, will use the encoding specified
>     for form   parameters
> - Unfortunately, IE5+ will not look at accept-charset unless   at least one
>     character in the form's values is not
>     in the   page's charset. Since the
>     user can override the default
>     charset (which Rails sets to UTF-8),
>     we provide a hidden   input containing
>     a unicode character, forcing IE to
>     look   at the accept-charset.
> - Now that the vast majority of web input is UTF-8, we set   the inbound
>     parameters to UTF-8. This will
>     eliminate many   cases of incompatible
>     encodings between ASCII-8BIT and
>     UTF-8.
> - You can safely ignore params[:_snowman]

In short, you can safely ignore this parameter.

Still, I am not sure why we're supporting old technologies like Internet Explorer 5. It seems like a very non-Ruby on Rails decision if you ask me.

**To really remove snowman try:**

Avoid using form_tag and it works:

```
<form action="<%= your_path %>" method="get" >
  <%= text_field_tag 'any_field' %>
  <%= submit_tag "submit name", :name => nil%>
</form>
```

Comment: But, do I really need to show utf8 parameter in URL?

Comment: It helps IE to really use utf-8.

Comment: There is other way to do it? Because the URL get ugly. I would like to show only /user/:id